# Grails Gorm DomainClass Inheritance with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, abstract-class

I seemed to have stumbled upon a bug in grails gorm/hibernate with mysql.

I have an abstractDomainClass which is under sources/groovy.  In this abstract domain class I have defined a manytomany relationship.

Then I have defined a DomainClass which inherites from the abstract domain class.  Now when I use this with MicrosftSQL Server it all works fine, but when I try to use this with MySQL I get the folowing error message:

```
Caused by MappingException: Foreign key (FK96018AD68612E650:domain_class [])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (user_group [id])
```

**My abstractDomainClass lookse like this:**

```
abstract class AbstractDomainClass {
    String name

    Set<UserGroup> userGroups

    static hasMany = [userGroups: UserGroup]

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }

    String toString() {
        return name
    }
}
```

**My DomainClass looks like this:**

```
class DomainClass extends AbstractDomainClass {
    String earliestEntryDate

    static constraints = {
        earliestEntryDate(nullable: true, blank: false, attributes: [sortable: false])
    }

}
```

**The UserGroup Domain class looks like this**

```
class UserGroup {
    String name

    static hasMany = [domainClasses: DomainClass]

    static belongsTo = [DomainClass]

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        name
    }
}
```

Comment: i think there is a duplicate path in your relationship ,hasMany and BelongsTo referring the same class plus inhering

Comment: You mean the UserGroup classm that was a Typo, fixed the hasMany from DomainClass: to DomainClasses:

Comment: fyi - `Set<UserGroup> userGroups` is redundant. Gorm by default creates a Set collection for hasMany relationship, so hasMany = [userGroups: UserGroup] will create a Set<UserGroup> userGroups.

Comment: for whatever reason it did not do that, maybe because it is an abstractClass in the sources groovy, and not under Domain ...